# Springer special issue status

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, springer

I submitted a paper to a special issue of a Springer journal.

The notification was supposed to be few days ago.
On that day, the current status became "review completed" and "Submissions with Production Completed (1)".

However, today the status changed to "Reviewer Assignment Pending" but there is still "Submissions with Production Completed (1)". 
Does it mean that the paper is gonna reviewed again? (even though it has already been reviewed) or does it mean that an editor is going to make the final decision ?

Comment: A very specific question. In general I wouldn't assign too much importance to what the electronic systems says. You may want to drop an email to the editor.

Comment: @Dilworth You are right, maybe I should email the editor to ask more information about that.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the "submissions with production completed" are submissions to the special issue which are ready for publication online. The (1) just means there's one such submission. It's not your submission, which is why the review status changing still leaves 1 submission ready. However, it's surprising because I would not have thought this information would be available to all authors contributing to the special issue.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that the comments posted were really the answer to this question, so I will say it:

You should email the editor to find out the status of your paper. While such online status updates are meant to be helpful, their terminology can be opaque (as you have seen) and they don't accurately reflect the nuance of the peer review process. The change you note could mean that, yes, you paper is going to another reviewer, or that perhaps your paper has been assigned to an internal reviewer among the editors of the special issue, or it could just be a random mistake.

I do suspect that by now the situation has resolved itself, but anyone else who is having questions about online status updates for peer review would be best placed to get in contact with the human behind them if accurate or detailed information is important.